# Pinch Zoom/Multitouch functionality on Android GridView

Tags: android, gridview, pinch

I am looking for an optimized way of implementing Pinch Zoom feature on my GirdView containing images. Why optimized? Because playing with Bitmaps any day gifts me with Out of Memory exception. Till date I have implemented the handling of Multitouch on screen by using          switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
in my onTouch event and getting to the case of "MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE".
Further I have been rebuilding the grid by calling the Adapter again and again on every case of pinch zoom in or out but one or the other moment I get out of memory exception.
Also I have tracked the intensity of pinch by taking the difference of coordinates between the old touch point and new touch point (using the trigonometry formulae: [(x2-x1)^2 +(y2-y2)^2]^1/2 ).

To summarize I am looking for help/suggestions on two points:
1) The way I have been tracking the intensity of Pinch Zoom in/out, is this a correct way?
2) What will be an optimized way of rebuilding the grid after the detection of pinch zoom in/out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Extend the grid view and make your own class, make a custom grid view and set the gesturelistener in that gridview and it will work out(if u need it in version > android 2.1) , i think...!!!!!!